# Does android PhoneStateListener run on background?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, phone-state-listener

I'm currently working on an android application to monitor the incoming and outgoing calls from a phone and register the call info into a file, and from what I've read `PhoneStateListener` seems to do what I need.

The thing is I need the application to run on background and I was thinking of using a service for that, but every example I've found that uses the listener declares it in the main activity, so I'm not sure if I **need** to create a service for it to run on background.

For a little more context, I have specific instructions that I can't create an application to "replace" the default calling app, so there's not much use in creating a GUI (I know the app needs a main activity, but it's only functionality should be starting the monitor).

The idea I have at the moment looks something like:

```kotlin
class CallMonitorService : Service() {
  private lateinit var serviceLooper: Looper
  private lateinit var serviceHandler: ServiceHandler
  private lateinit var monitor: StateMonitor

  private inner class ServiceHandler(looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {...}
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    Log.d(serviceName, "Created")
    HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND).apply {
      start()
      // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
      serviceLooper = looper
      serviceHandler = ServiceHandler(looper)
      val manager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
      manager.listen(StateMonitor(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE | ...)
    }
  }
  ...
}

class StateMonitor : PhoneStateListener() {
  // Handler methods
}
```

So, as a summary, I need the `PhoneStateListener` to be running at all moments, without the need of an app to be running on foreground.
Should I create a service to run the listener on background or the listener runs on background by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've solved the issue.

The short answer is **no**, the `PhoneStateListener` doesn't run in background.
By default the listener runs only when the application is in foreground for what I've seen.

Maybe there's a way to run it in a service but I couldn't get it to work.
Instead I solved the problem with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

So, for the solution

The `CallStateMonitor` stayed the same as it was before, I just moved it from where it was.
For the service, as I said, I replaced it for a broadcast receiver:

```kotlin
class CallBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val telephonyManager = context?.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val monitor = StateMonitor()
    telephonyManager.listen(monitor, LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
  }

  private val tag = "STATE_MONITOR"

  private inner class StateMonitor : PhoneStateListener() {
    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String?) {
      when (state) {
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> Log.d(tag, "IDLE")
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> Log.d(tag, "OFF-HOOK")
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> Log.d(tag, "RINGING")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The rest is just starting the receiver from the main activity:

```kotlin
class CallMonitorActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    registerReceiver(CallBroadcastReceiver(), IntentFilter(ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED))
    Log.d(ACTIVITY_TAG, "Registered call receiver.")
  }
}
```

And that's it, hope it can help someone else ^-^

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your listener into `Service` that will be running standalone. The service is already in "background", so you don't need to create extra thread. Moreover, from what you have posted there is no code that is blocking code, all your events will be sent in callback manner.

Comment: So would it be a good idea to use the state listener inside my service?